# JQuery AJAX Post fails on Android Tablets Running Honeycomb 3.2

Tags: android, ajax, jquery, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a simple enough AJAX `'POST'`.  It works on IOS phones and tablets (4.0 and 5) and appears to work on Android phones (2.1 and 4.0) but when it is run on two different android tablets both using Honeycomb 3.2 the `errorcallback` is executed everytime - even though the webservice recieves the post successfully.

```
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          cache: false,
          data: data,
          success: callback,
          error:(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
          {
            alert(jqXHR); // [object, object]
            alert(textStatus); // "error"
            alert(errorThrown); // empty
          },
          crossDomain:true,  // This option has no effect on the outcome
          dataType: 'JSON'
        });
```

I am successfully using JQuery's ajax `'GET'` across all platforms its just the `'POST'` i'm having problem with.  CORS is enabled on the server.   Anyone come across this problem before?  I tried to boot up the emulator to write out the errors but LOG cat just ignored them so I resorted to using alerts.

Interestingly when I navigate away from the page the success callback appears to fire...

Comment: what is the error code getting returned when errorCallback is getting called..there must be some error message returned..can you paste that here..

Comment: I'm just working on some error messages.  I don't suppose you know of a way to access console.log() in the android browser do you?

Comment: Are you getting ? `NetworkOnMainThreadException` ? Just confirm cause Honeycomb comes with StrictMode

Comment: @user1042031 changing cache didn't help